# How to retrieve all my active Facebook ads?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-insights, facebook-marketing-api

I'm creating a dashboard for myself that helps me keep track of the Facebook ads I'm running.

What I've not been able to figure out is:

**How can I retrieve an array of ad IDs for all ads that are active *or* could soon be active after no further action on my part?**

In other words, I want all ads that I've set to Active and that exist within Adsets and Campaigns that are active (and therefore these ads are live right now)... *plus* all the ads that from *my* perspective are Active but that Facebook has set to another status such as Pending Review (and will soon set back to Active).

I have some code below, but the problem is that it *also* accidentally includes Pending ads that--once reviewed and approved by Facebook--will be inactive rather than active (because I've set them that way).  And I do NOT want this type of ad to be included in my report.

My report should only show me ones where I'm actively spending money or have the potential to spend money as soon as FB approves them.

I think I understand the difference between `configured_status` and `effective_status` in `AbstractArchivableCrudObjectFields`, but I don't know that it's enough to help me because I have lots of ads set to Active that are within Adsets that are Inactive, and I don't want to see those listed in my report.

Any recommendations?

```
public function getActiveAdIds() {
    $key = 'activeAdIds';
    $adIdsJson = Cache::get($key);
    if ($adIdsJson) {
        $adIds = json_decode($adIdsJson);
    } else {
        $adsResponse = $this->getAdsByStatus([ArchivableCrudObjectEffectiveStatuses::ACTIVE, ArchivableCrudObjectEffectiveStatuses::PENDING_REVIEW]);
        $ads = $adsResponse->data;
        $adIds = [];
        foreach ($ads as $ad) {
            $adIds[] = $ad->id;
        }
        $adIdsJson = json_encode($adIds);
        Cache::put($key, $adIdsJson, 1);
    }
    return $adIds;
}

public function getAdsByStatus($statuses) {
    $params = [\FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AbstractArchivableCrudObjectFields::EFFECTIVE_STATUS => $statuses];
    $adAccount = new AdAccount(self::ACT_PREPEND . $this->fbConfig['account_id']);
    $cursor = $adAccount->getAds([], $params);
    $response = $cursor->getResponse();
    $jsonString = $response->getBody();
    return json_decode($jsonString);
}
```

Comment: Any chance for you to share, how you solved this problem?

Comment: @Sigismund Still unsolved. If you find out, I'd love if you'd post the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I get stats based on assets for my active campaigns. I have 119 ad accounts. This is php code which I used it for this purpose (any suggestion to improve it will be appreciated):

```
    $fields = array(AdsInsightsFields::ACCOUNT_NAME,AdsInsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_ID,
                    AdsInsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_NAME, AdsInsightsFields::ADSET_ID,
                    AdsInsightsFields::ADSET_NAME,AdsInsightsFields::DATE_START,
                    AdsInsightsFields::DATE_STOP,AdsInsightsFields::REACH,
                    AdsInsightsFields::SPEND, AdsInsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
                    AdsInsightsFields::CLICKS, AdsInsightsFields::WEBSITE_CLICKS,
                    AdsInsightsFields::CALL_TO_ACTION_CLICKS,AdsInsightsFields::ACTIONS,
                    AdsInsightsFields::TOTAL_ACTIONS,AdsInsightsFields::CPC,
                    AdsInsightsFields::CPM,AdsInsightsFields::CPP,
                    AdsInsightsFields::CTR,AdsInsightsFields::OBJECTIVE,);
    $params_c['date_preset'] = AdDatePresetValues::YESTERDAY;
    $params_c['time_increment'] = 1;
    $params_c['action_attribution_windows'] = array('1d_view', '28d_click');
    $params_c['effective_status'] = AdStatusValues::ACTIVE;
    $params_c['level'] = AdsInsightsLevelValues::ADSET;
    $params_c['filtering'] = [array("field"=>"campaign.delivery_info", 
                                   "operator"=>"IN",
                                    "value"=>array("active"))];
    $params_c['fields']= $fields;     
    try{
         // Initialize a new Session and instanciate an Api object
        Api::init(self::api_key, self::secret_token, self::extended_token)->getHttpClient()->setCaBundlePath( $this->path_cert);

        // The Api object is now available trough singleton
        $api = Api::instance();
        $user = new \FacebookAds\Object\Business($business_id);
        $user->read(array(BusinessFields::ID));

        //get all ad_account from Business
        $accounts = $user->getAssignedAdAccounts(
                      array(
                    AdAccountFields::ID,
                 ),
                  array('limit'=>1000,)
                );                                    

    } catch (FacebookAds\Exception\Exception $ex) {
        return $ex->getMessage();
    }   

    if(isset($accounts) && ($accounts->count() > 0)):           
        do{

            $ad_account = $accounts->current();            
            $adset_insights = $ad_account->getInsights($fields,$params_c); 

            do {
                $adset_insights->fetchAfter();
            } while ($adset_insights->getNext());

            $adsets = $adset_insights->getArrayCopy(true); 
    }
    while ($accounts->current());    
    endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Although your code looks like it will probably help someone, I wonder if you don't understand the main part of my question (relating to the difference between `configured_status` and `effective_status` and how to retrieve all ads that either are actively spending money or could be approved by Facebook to spend money without any further action on my part).

Answer (score 0):

If you include the `adset{end_time}` field in the query for the ad, you can assume that ad is not actually running if the end_time was in the past. This is how we get a base list of ads to query on.

The next step we take (which probably won't help you, unfortunately, but may help others) is building a batch of simple requests (one per ad) to see if there are any insights data for that day. If the response is an empty 'data' array, we can remove that ID from the ad list.

After we've reduced the size of the ad list with those two steps we can then make requests to run all of our breakdown reports. This method almost cut our API requests in half.

I have yet to find a way to do a "give me all ads that are for sure running this day" query in one step.

Edit:
I just found a better way to do this.... :

```
curl -G \
-d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
-d 'level=campaign' \
-d 'filtering=[{field:"ad.impressions",operator:"GREATER_THAN",value:0}]' \
'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/act_<ACCOUNT_ID>/insights'
```